Do either Python or AWS Glue provide an alternative to .NET's SqlBulkCopy?
I am porting an old SSIS package to AWS Glue. The package runs daily. In several steps in this package, I take data from one table on one Microsoft SQL Server and copy all of it to an empty table of identical schema on another  Microsoft SQL Server. I wish to replicate these steps in AWS Glue. This would be rather easy if I could write code in C# or PowerShell's dbatools because, like SSIS, they all use SqlBulkCopy either directly or indirectly. Unfortunately, I am under the following restrictions:

If I am using a system where I can pick a language and one of the options is Python, then I must use either Python or SQL embedded in Python. I believe that IronPython is not an option.
My copying must get the same or better performance as SSIS. In other words, I need SqlBulkCopy or an equivalent.
AWS Glue must be involved. It is allowed to call other services, e.g. Lambda and Step Functions.

With these restrictions in mind, what options do I have? Do either Python or AWS Glue provide an alternative to .NET's SqlBulkCopy?

https://github.com/denisenkom/pytds seem to support bulk, although, i'm not sure if it supports server to server bulk through resultsets like SqlBulkCopy, if that's what you're using. You can also use jaydebeapi that wraps java jdbc which does SQLBulkCopy and perhaps spark jdbc supports bulk directly as well, not sure if will be exactly as fast as SSIS though

pymssql Supports bulk copy.

@JonSG Amazing. Awesome. Super! Rewrite that as an example showing a copy from one server to another and you will have fully answered this question.

pymssql needs the FreeTDS driver installed. Are you able to install drivers in AWS Glue? Or do you need a pure Python solution?

@AlwaysLearning I'll give it a try, but I'm pretty sure that I can install drivers in Glue.

@AlwaysLearning Interestingly, our SQL library is sqlalchemy, but out connection string is using pymssql. Is that sufficient?

sqlalchemy is just an ORM, it relies on modules like pyodbc and pymssql to provide connectivity and protocol support for different database backends.

@AlwaysLearning So what I have should be sufficient?

@JonSG Fancy grabbing this bounty?

I appreciate the nod, but all I did was point out a link to some patch notes. If you wanted to expand on it with a real answer and maybe some example code I would certainly upvote you.

AWS Glue uses Pyspark, which supports connectors for MSSQL and Bulk Copy. So if you use df.write, it uses the Bulk Copy.

Also as a side note, you mentioned you prefer Python or SQL embedded in Python. I'd recommend you use SparkSQL. You run something like spark.sql("YOUR SQL QUERY") and write the resulting df to your desired MSSQL db.

@ParmanM.Alizadeh I'd enjoy seeing a bulk copy example posted as an answer.

Your question doesn't ask for any code @J.Mini, maybe you should write another one, if you have any specific issues with spark sql or any of the other libraries mentioned in the comments. Here's some code after a quick google though: https://medium.com/@uzzaman.ahmed/pyspark-dataframe-api-read-and-write-data-from-databases-5b58548d1baa
